# Compiling boost 1.62/1.63 with zlib on windows

Tags: c++, boost, zlib

I know this probably looks like a duplicate, but it is actually a new issue I encountered. A ticket is opened on boost side, but no one is answering... (https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/12505#comment:12)

My issue is simple: I am following the same steps as with any other boost version (by setting ZLIB_INCLUDE AND ZLIB_LIBPATH) but since 1.62 I get a strange error:

```
Name clash for '<pbin.v2\standalone\ac\msvc-14.0\debug\address-model-64\link-static\threading-multi>main.obj'
...
error: Tried to build the target twice, with property sets having                                                                                                                                                                       
error: these incompatible properties:                                                                                                                                                                                                   
error:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
error:     -  <dll-path>... <library-path>... <xdll-path>...
```

I also tried to do it by configuring a custom user-config.jam but end up with the same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who are interested, if you apply this diff (which will come along boost 1.64) then everything works fine: https://github.com/boostorg/build/commit/373fb6f76962caca9da109d4fe1e820af996326d?diff=unified.